docker-compose not working when changing mysql host port
This is the part of my docker-compose.yml file regarding the mysql instace:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0.32
    mem_limit: 512m
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=****
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=review-db
      - MYSQL_USER=user
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=****
    healthcheck:
      test: "/usr/bin/mysql --user=user --password-pwd --execute \"SHOW DATABASES;\""
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 2s
      retries: 60

when I run docker-compose up on this file I get an error bc the 3306 on my machine is already taken from my own personal mysql instance. So I changed it to 3307:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0.32
    mem_limit: 512m
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=****
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=review-db
      - MYSQL_USER=user
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=****
    healthcheck:
      test: "/usr/bin/mysql --user=user --password-pwd --execute \"SHOW DATABASES;\""
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 2s
      retries: 60

but now I get
ERROR: for mysql  'ContainerConfig'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/docker-compose", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('docker-compose==1.29.2', 'console_scripts', 'docker-compose')())
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 81, in main
    command_func()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 203, in perform_command
    handler(command, command_options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages/compose/metrics/decorator.py", line 18, in wrapper
    result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 1186, in up
    to_attach = up(False)
                ^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 1166, in up
    return self.project.up(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages/compose/project.py", line 697, in up
    results, errors = parallel.parallel_execute(
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages/compose/parallel.py", line 108, in parallel_execute
    raise error_to_reraise
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages/compose/parallel.py", line 206, in producer
    result = func(obj)
             ^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages/compose/project.py", line 679, in do
    return service.execute_convergence_plan(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages/compose/service.py", line 579, in execute_convergence_plan
    return self._execute_convergence_recreate(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages/compose/service.py", line 499, in _execute_convergence_recreate
    containers, errors = parallel_execute(
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages/compose/parallel.py", line 108, in parallel_execute
    raise error_to_reraise
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages/compose/parallel.py", line 206, in producer
    result = func(obj)
             ^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages/compose/service.py", line 494, in recreate
    return self.recreate_container(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages/compose/service.py", line 612, in recreate_container
    new_container = self.create_container(
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages/compose/service.py", line 330, in create_container
    container_options = self._get_container_create_options(
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages/compose/service.py", line 921, in _get_container_create_options
    container_options, override_options = self._build_container_volume_options(
                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages/compose/service.py", line 960, in _build_container_volume_options
    binds, affinity = merge_volume_bindings(
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages/compose/service.py", line 1548, in merge_volume_bindings
    old_volumes, old_mounts = get_container_data_volumes(
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages/compose/service.py", line 1579, in get_container_data_volumes
    container.image_config['ContainerConfig'].get('Volumes') or {}
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: 'ContainerConfig'


I've looked around and ppl say this error is caused by the use of docker-compose up (which is what I'm using) instead of docker compose up... but why does it arise when I change my host port? And how do I fix it?
EDIT
I've shut down my own personal mysql instance with systemctl stop mysqld freeing the 3306 port. I've set the docker-compose.yml to 3306:3306 and given again docker-compose up. All starts now... so my questions remain

did you try removing the quotes on ports? ports:       - 3306:3306

docker-compose run issue 2024: Error: 'ContainerConfig' suggests that something in current Docker has broken the old Python-based version of Compose.  Can you use the newer plugin-based version of Compose?
